# HTML input tag file handling

Tags: html, file

In this code for the PDF reader [pdf-js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) there is an `input` tag to let the user upload an input file

```
 <input id="fileInput" class="fileInput" type="file" oncontextmenu="return false;" style="visibility: hidden; position: fixed; right: 0; top: 0" />
```

This `input` tag is not a part of any form. Once the user uploads the file, where does it go? Where is the code that processes the file? (I'm asking in general, not necessarily specific to this piece of code.)

Comment: You have to set the path in a server side language, say like PHP, and it will go there. Else it will just go to some temp folder if I am not wrong. And this tag has to be a part of some form.

Comment: Then it's interesting. This code doesn't have server side.

Comment: First: every uploaded file goes to temp folder and then server side script move it to another folder. Second: pdf-js use javascript so there is no need of some form ;)

Comment: @furas So where would be the Javascript code that handles the uploaded file?

Comment: There is no uploading in that viewer. Viewer use input file to open file in browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "Then it's interesting. This code doesn't have server side"

No, It doesn't.

Pdf.js is a client side program that written with javascript. So that works on javascript side.

It actually takes the file that you wanna show, and does whatever must be done like converting the buffer to Uint8Array than renders it.

All processes happen on javascript side. No server side, no file upload.

[Here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) is an article about reading local files in javascript

Here is the related part of code in [pdf.viewer.js](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.js)

```
window.addEventListener('change', function webViewerChange(evt) {
  var files = evt.target.files;
  if (!files || files.length === 0)
    return;

  // Read the local file into a Uint8Array.
  var fileReader = new FileReader();
  fileReader.onload = function webViewerChangeFileReaderOnload(evt) {
    var buffer = evt.target.result;
    var uint8Array = new Uint8Array(buffer);
    PDFView.open(uint8Array, 0);
  };

  var file = files[0];
  fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  PDFView.setTitleUsingUrl(file.name);

  // URL does not reflect proper document location - hiding some icons.
  document.getElementById('viewBookmark').setAttribute('hidden', 'true');
  document.getElementById('download').setAttribute('hidden', 'true');
}, true);
```

Comment: +1 you found the same article about reading local files in javascript :)